Calculating the moment of inertia of a 2D convex polygon for physics
I have made a quick and basic working demo on calculating the moment of inertia of a 2D convex polygon. This was for the purpose of learning physics engines, more specifically rigid body dynamics (2D) for fun. However, inertia can be complicated subject (especially in 3D) and that there seems to be many different answers and methods online on calculating inertia in 2D. There is also moments of inertia in engineering that is not related in my use case which also adds to the confusion when researching online.
After finding a potential solution, I have decided to use a variation of the following formulas from one of the commenters, arildno, in an old forum in Physics Forums as well as an answer from a math stackexchange post by juhl for the code. The formulas are pretty much the same.
$$
I=\frac{m}{6}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}||\vec{P}_{n+1}\times\vec{P}_{n}||(\vec{P}^{2}_{n+1}+\vec{P}_{n+1}\cdot\vec{P}_{n}+\vec{P}_{n}^{2})}{\sum_{n=1}^{N}||\vec{P}_{n+1}\times\vec{P}_{n}||}
$$
$$
I_0 = \frac{m}{6} \frac{ \sum_{i=0}^{i=N-1} ( x_i^2 + y_i^2 + x_i x_{i+1} + y_i y_{i+1} + x_{i+1}^2 + y_{i+1}^2 ) ( x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i ) }{ \sum_{i=0}^{i=N-1} ( x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i ) }
$$
I think the formulas are related to Green's Theorem (it was mentioned on some papers that I was researching) but I don't have the advanced knowledge to understand it fully.
The polygon used in the demo is a pentagon at the center with a sidelength of 265mm and a mass of 42.9kg. These values are from a comment in the same forum by the user GINGERBEER for testing the program.
Polygon Image (Units are in meters)
For the program, I have made the assumption that the polygon center/centroid is at (0, 0) for the scope of this program. This is to simplify calculations since I would probably need to involve calculating the centroid and the Parallel Axis Theorem which is trivial and not necessary for this demo for now.
The code requires the number of vertices and the shapes mass for calculations which I provided. The shape is created from the points that I have also provided. The area of the shape is then calculated as it is required to calculate the moment of inertia, seen from the equations above. Then the program calculates the moment of inertia using the equations above.
Code
// inertia_demo.c

#include <stddef.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct dvec2 {
        double x;
        double y;
};


void print_shape(struct dvec2 const *shape, size_t vert_num);

double shape_calc_area(struct dvec2 const *shape, size_t vert_num);
double shape_calc_mmoi(struct dvec2 const *shape, size_t vert_num, double mass,
double area);


int main()
{
        size_t vert_num = 5;
        double mass = 42.9;
        
        printf("vert_num\t= %ld\n", vert_num);
        printf("mass\t\t= %f kg\n", mass);
        
        // example polygon shape with side length of 265 mm or 0.265 m.
        // the polygon is at the center of (0, 0). in this case, the centroid is
        // ignored in the later calculations for the scope of this demo.

        struct dvec2 pentagon[5] = {
                {  0.000000,  0.225422 }, // points are mathematically derived
                { -0.214390,  0.069659 }, // from side length of shape.
                { -0.132500, -0.182371 },
                {  0.132500, -0.182371 },
                {  0.214390,  0.069659 }
        }; 

        // note that points are anti-clockwise since some formulas can return
        // signed values. 

        print_shape(pentagon, vert_num);

        double area = shape_calc_area(pentagon, vert_num);
        printf("area\t\t= %f m2\n", area);
        
        double mmoi = shape_calc_mmoi(pentagon, vert_num, mass, area);
        printf("mmoi\t\t= %f kg m2\n", mmoi);

        return 0;
}


void print_shape(struct dvec2 const *shape, size_t vert_num)
{
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vert_num; i++) {
                printf("vrt[%zu]\t\t= (%f, %f)\n", i, shape[i].x, shape[i].y);
        }
}

// points in shape are anti-clockwise since `shape_calc_area` returns a signed 
// area.
double shape_calc_area(struct dvec2 const *shape, size_t vert_num)
{
        double area = 0.0;
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vert_num; i++) {
                size_t j = (i + 1) % vert_num;
                
                area += shape[i].x * shape[j].y - shape[j].x * shape[i].y;
        }
        
        area *= 0.5;
        
        return area;
}


double shape_calc_mmoi(struct dvec2 const *shape, size_t vert_num, double mass, 
double area)
{
        double mmoi = 0.0;
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vert_num; i++) {
                size_t j = (i + 1) % vert_num;
                double tmp = 0.0;
                
                tmp += (shape[i].x * shape[i].x) + (shape[j].x * shape[j].x);
                tmp += (shape[i].y * shape[i].y) + (shape[j].y * shape[j].y);
                tmp += (shape[i].x * shape[j].x) + (shape[i].y * shape[j].y);
                tmp *= (shape[i].x * shape[j].y) - (shape[j].x * shape[i].y);
                
                mmoi += tmp;
        }
        
        mmoi *= mass;
        mmoi /= area * 12.0; // not 6.0 seen in the equations since area is 
                             // already multiplied by 0.5 in the area function.
        
        return mmoi;
}

My concerns with the demo are the following.

When comparing my answer (I = 0.838934) to GINGERBEER (I = 0.835960338), it is mostly similar however I am unsure whether we both have made minor mistakes (maybe rounding and floats?) on our own part. I also tested in online calculator (I = 0.839), it is seemingly equal to my answer. From this, I feel confident that the demo seems to be working. However, because there are many different answers on calculating inertia online, I am still not sure.

To hopefully clear confusion and give some confirmation for the reasons listed above, is this a valid implementation of computing inertia in my use case for physics (for physics and 2D rigid body dynamics)?



FWIW: I think the formula you are using (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) has the sneaky feature that the vertices are to be numbered cyclically, so that  $P_N$ is followed by $P_{N+1}=P_0$. Thus if you have five vertices, you will have a sum of five expressions, each involving a pair of consecutive vertices. It is easy to accidentally leave out that last one.

Disclaimer: Taking the formula as presented in the question as correct and applicable.
No attempt is made to address the 'physics' aspect of the OP's concerns.

Overview
The code is clean and very readable.
Suggest changing to using only "4 spaces per tabstop" instead of 8.
Note: C understands floating point numbers and their basic arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /).
#include <math.h> is unnecessary as this code does not call any math library functions (eg: sin(), round(), etc.), nor use any math constants (eg: PI).
There's no real harm caused by including the extra library header file, except that a pedantic reader is misled by the second line of this source code.

size_t
Kudos for the use of size_t variables as loop counter and array index variables.
Tiny, inconsequential 'oops' in this statement where %zu should be used:
printf("vert_num\t= %ld\n", vert_num);

Needless function prototypes
Re-organising the function definitions so that each is defined prior to its invocation allows the C compiler to use each function's definition as its own prototype. (Typically, this means main() would appear at the bottom of the program listing for a single file program such as this.) This organisation eliminates the need for explicit forward declarations (and the maintenance thereof) in a small program.

To qualify or not to qualify, that is the question...
const appears in the code appropriately, but sporadically.
Paramount is that the code functions correctly. Adding qualifiers such as const or static may be only bulking-up small programs and should be left to later revisions as a program grows when the extra benefits they provide becomes warranted (imho).

Don't bury the lead
shape_calc_mmoi() deals with (a pointer, named shape, to) an array.
Once the reader has seen the function signature, the pointer's name is retained while its use is examined... Consider the following in contrast to the OP's code:
double shape_calc_mmoi(struct dvec2 *S, size_t vert_num, double mass, double area)
{
        ...
                double tmp = 0.0;
                
                tmp += (S[i].x * S[i].x) + (S[j].x * S[j].x);
                tmp += (S[i].y * S[i].y) + (S[j].y * S[j].y);
                tmp += (S[i].x * S[j].x) + (S[i].y * S[j].y);
                tmp *= (S[i].x * S[j].y) - (S[j].x * S[i].y);
                
        ...
}

Sixteen occurrences of shape, replaced by S, de-obscure the significant values that are indices and element identifiers. The reader can better discern what is i from j, and what is x from y. A reader comfortable with precedence might even notice that the parentheses are not required.
Since the summation deals with operations performed on adjacent array elements, one might even improve on the hard-to-resolve distinction between i and j by using pointers instead:
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vert_num; i++) {
                struct dvec2 *P = S + i; // ptr to current vertex
                struct dvec2 *Q = S + ((i + 1) % vert_num); // ptr to next vertex (ccw)
                double tmp =
                       (P->x * P->x) + (Q->x * Q->x)
                    +  (P->y * P->y) + (Q->y * Q->y)
                    +  (P->x * Q->x) + (P->y * Q->y);
                tmp *= (P->x * Q->y) - (Q->x * P->y);
                
                mmoi += tmp;
        }

(At 4AM, one's bleary eyes tend to be blind to an i where a j should be, or vice versa.)

Simplification?
Now that the body of the largest for() loop has been reduced in size, it may be worth considering combining the two summation loops in the two functions into a single loop. Perhaps the output statements are built into this function, too, or appropriate changes made to return two double values to the caller. It's up to the OP to decide if visiting each of the polygon's vertices twice is appropriate. Might these functions be called independently of one-another?, or are their results mutually reliant?

All-in-all, a good rendition of the formula expressed in C.

Adding unnecessary headers can increase compile time. This isn't such a problem anymore, but back in the bad old days a single file might take a minute or two to compile. Reducing compile time by removing unnecessary headers was a good thing.

@pacmaninbw Agreed... mostly.... Back in those "bad old days", the 'cost' of performing a build impelled coders to strive for unattainable 'perfection'. As costs went down, so did the locus of responsibility migrate into the compiler... Now, every failed plumber's apprentice is a "software engineer"...

@Fe2O3 In general I agree to not include unrequired . Yet an advantage to including a header file that does not appear to be needed:  collision detection - when a user code global identifier matches a standard one. OP here does not appear to attempting that so your advice holds. Yet in general, perhaps in a debug build, it is useful to add some to many unneeded  simply to not step on some standard C identifier. Certainly including all standard headers hinders compile time, but does catch some collisions from time2time.

@chux You're right (and thanks for the link). My only (long ago) 'brush' with "portability" was a large-ish app extending DOS to run on UNIX. I don't recall encountering (m)any "naming conflicts", but adjusting those damnable back vs. forward slashes in pathnames sure occupied too many hours!! Cheers! :-)

Create a struct for shapes
struct dvec2 is just a single coordinate, but you are passing shapes around a lot, which involves a pointer to an array of coordinates and its size. So:
struct shape {
    struct dvec2 *vertices;
    size_t num_vertices;
};

You could go further and also realize that a shape plus a mass together is a body, so it makes sense to declare:
struct body {
    struct shape shape;
    double mass;
};

Naming things
Avoid unnecessary abbreviations. Consider vert_num: does it stand for "vertex number", "number of vertices", "vertical number"? It would be better to just write out vertices, and use num_ or even n_ as a prefix, as that is a more common and less ambiguous way to represent "number of".
Also try to be as consistent as possible. When naming functions, either start with a verb like in print_shape(), but then also write calculate_shape_area(). Alternatively, consistently start with the type a function works on like in shape_calculate_area(), but then also write shape_print().
Floating point rounding
Floating point arithmetic does suffer from rounding errors, especially if you sum a lot of numbers together, which you potentially do. However, for a pentagon I would not expect a large error. Normally a double has a precision of ~16 digits, so a discrepancy in the third digit of the answer is definitely not coming from just floating point rounding errors!
I did notice though that you created the shape by hardcoding the coordinates using only 6 decimals. That's already limiting your precision. Since you have a programming language at your disposal, I recommend just writing a function to generate the coordinates of the vertices of a pentagon using some trigonometry. There is also less chance of making a typo in those numbers then.
It could be GINGERBEER made some approximations of their own that limited the accuracy of their answer.
Consider adding links to the formulas used
If someone unfamiliar with the mathematics behind the moment of inertia calculation is reading your code, they will not understand why you do all these multiplications and additions. Consider adding some comments with links to Wikipedia and/or Mathworld to the code.

Good idea about linking formulas.
